# Select object in array by item number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get `url` from the second `[2]` `object` in this `array`.

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://example1.jpg",
  },
  {
    "url": "https://example2.jpg",
  },
  {
    "url": "https://example3.jpg",
  },            
]
```

I had thought that I could do as

```
<div
  className="event-image"
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${i.images.map(d => {
      d.url[2];
    })})`,
  }}
/>
```

However, it returns as `,,,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just access the second image and then it's url:

```
<div
  className="event-image"
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${i.images[1].url})`,
  }}
/>
```

Array indexes are zero-based, so the second image is at index 1

Comment: Cheers - I love to overcomplicate things. Will accept in 7 minutes as it allows.